# how to make a variable global inside a function

Tags: python, global

How do you declare a variable as global once it has been created inside a function?
This is my example code (not what it is being used for):

```
def function():
    pancakes = input("pancakes input")
    pancakes = global(pancakes) #i don't know how to do this part

def function2(pancakes):
    print(pancakes)
    
function()
function2(pancakes)
```

By the way I know that returning the variable also works but it will not with my program.

Comment: use global keyword variable before you assignment.like global val val=1

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you please give an example using the code I provided? @NAGA RAJ S

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function

Comment: You can't turn a local variable into a global one, and even if it could be done you would likely be better off using a different code structure. You can, however, update a preexisting global variable within your function.

Comment: yes thank you Ghost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare a variable in the global scope (outside the function) and assign a value to it inside the function.

```
pancakes = None
def function():
    global pancakes
    pancakes_input = input("pancakes input")
    pancakes = pancakes_input

def function2(pancakes):
    print(pancakes)
    
function()
function2(pancakes)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to make the variable global using a global keyword every time you assign the value to that variable .and if it is the main thread means there is no need to use the global keyword. follow this:

```
var=0

def func():
   global var
   var=1
```